# How to Use Ionic 2 Navbar API

Tags: ionic2

I am using documentation 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/navbar/Navbar/

while using this api, i have injected dependency  Navbar to my page.I can enable/disable backbutton with API. I wish to capture click on this button and nagivate using backButtonClick(). Can you tell me how to use this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Angular's @ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child). First, you inject the child component into the one we need to do an interaction:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Navbar } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyNavBar {
  @ViewChild(Navbar) navbar: Navbar;
}
```

Then, you can call your `backButtonClick` method:

```
this.navbar.backButtonClick = (e: UIEvent) => {
  // Print this event to the console
  console.log(e);

  // Navigate to another page
  this.navCtrl.push(AnotherPage);
}
```